# Text within button causing button to enlarge when viewing on small screens

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button with some CSS. When viewing the button on a large desktop, all appears ok.

However, if looking on a tablet for example, the text of the button flows over 2 lines.

Is there a way i can stop this?

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" title="Search" class="btn btn--green">Search Customer Details</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -ms-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);  
}

.btn--green {
  background: #3bb300;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #44cc00), color-stop(100%, #2a8000));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#44cc00, #2a8000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#44cc00, #2a8000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#44cc00, #2a8000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#44cc00, #2a8000);
  border: 1px solid #226600;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.btn--green:hover, .btn--green:focus, .btn--green[disabled] {
  background: #339900;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #3aad00), color-stop(100%, #297a00));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3aad00, #297a00);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#3aad00, #297a00);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#3aad00, #297a00);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3aad00, #297a00);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/S54bN/1/

Open the fiddle and resize the screen to see.

Comment: so you want shrink the text on button OR hide it when text overflow the button size?

Comment: I think shrink text would be better.. Is setting font-size as a percentage of the button width possible?

Comment: You could exchange your `width` for a `min-width`, and apply the `white-space` property to prevent the text from breaking into multiple lines under any circumstances … but of course then the button might cause scrollbars or flow out of its container. If that’s not what you want – well then you will have to be more specific on _what_ you actually want the behavior to be.

Comment: @OamPsy , well yes you can add percentage for font-size but that good practice to follow rather I would suggested solution given by CBore. I ask those because I was bit of confuse about your question.